# Customizing WSO2 IS login

Tags: spring-saml, wso2-identity-server

I've implemented a working environment with Spring SAML (2 service providers) and WSO2 IS v5.2.  This question do not pertain to visual styling of the login page as I have completed this.  The login page is hosted from the WSO2 server and is delivered with the following redirect url:

```
https://server/authenticationendpoint/login.do?commonAuthCallerPath=
%2Fsamlsso&forceAuth=false&passiveAuth=false&tenantDomain=carbon.super
&sessionDataKey=e779c512-fdf6-4787-ae40-d6ccccc052ec&
relyingParty=urn%foo%bar%3Atampa&type=samlsso&
sp=mysp&isSaaSApp=false&authenticators=BasicAuthenticator:LOCAL
```

I would like to know if the framework on the wso2 side allows for adding additional query-string params to the above URL.  I would like to add additional params to cause a certain behavior.  For example: an addition query-string argument could be username and I could pre-populate this value in the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible to pass any additional parameters as long as they don't share the same parameter names used by IS.

You may write an authenticator by extending "BasicAuthenticator" and overriding the initiateAuthenticationRequest().There you'll have to copy the method content from "BasicAuthenticator" class and append the redirect url built inside with your parameters. Then use this authenticator as the default one. You can still hack the BasicAuthenticator code itself too, but it's not recommended.